# JDBC Select all records from table, returns only 1

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Hi I want to select all records from Garaz table and add it to ArrayList (now it gives me only one Garaz from Garaz table), then return the ArrayList. Also if any Garaz contains cars (Auta) i want to list them too - for a particular Garaz (Garaz, Auta - names in Polish).

```
public class connection {

private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/garaz";
private static final String DB_USER = "root";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "";
static ArrayList <Garaz> lista = new ArrayList <Garaz>();
static ArrayList <Auto> lista2 = new ArrayList <Auto>();

public static ArrayList <Garaz> selectRecords() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    String selectTableSQL = "SELECT * from GARAZ";


            try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

        System.out.println(selectTableSQL);

        // execute select SQL stetement
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
                        int g_id = rs.getInt("G_ID");
        String nazwa = rs.getString("NAZWA");
        String adres = rs.getString("ADRES");
                        int lmiejsc = rs.getInt("LICZBAMIEJSC");
        int lpoz = rs.getInt("LICZBAPOZIOMOW");
                        boolean czynny = rs.getBoolean("CZYNNY");

            ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList <Auto>();


        int a_id = rs.getInt("A_Id");
            String model = rs.getString("Model");
            String kolor = rs.getString("Kolor");
            int ildrzwi = rs.getInt("IloscDrzwi");
            String rejestracja = rs.getString("Rejestracja");

            Auto d = new Auto(a_id, model, kolor, ildrzwi, rejestracja);
            if (a_id !=0){
            lista2.add(d);
            }
            Garaz f = new Garaz(g_id, nazwa, lista2, adres, lmiejsc, lpoz, czynny);
            lista.add(f);
                   // return lista;
                    }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }
    return lista;

}
```

Comment: You can do all this with a single SELECT statement. You don't need all this code.

Comment: So.What is your question..?? You already did it yourself.

Comment: Question is: Why my ArrayList <Garaz> lista contains only ONE record from Garaz table, NOT all of them ?

Comment: Later, in other class i have:  try{
         list = con.selectRecords();
      
      }catch(SQLException e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }                                                                        and this list has only ONE record from Garaz table NOT all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [`java.sql.Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one `ResultSet` object per `Statement` object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one `ResultSet` object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different `Statement` objects. All execution methods in the `Statement` interface implicitly close a statment's current `ResultSet` object if an open one exists.

If you want to execute another statement, while iterating over a `ResultSet`, you need to use a different `Statement` object to execute that statement, otherwise the first `ResultSet` will be closed.

Also: what you are doing can easily be achieved by a single statement using an `INNER JOIN` between `GARAZ` and `AUTA`, this is usually better for performance. Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM GARAZ g
INNER JOIN AUTA a ON a.G_ID = g.G_ID
```

Also **do not concatenate values** in a statement as that is vulnerable to SQL injection, conversion problems etc. Use a `PreparedStatement` with parameter placeholders.

Comment: hi, I was trying to make it work but i CANNOT :( I have all records from DB, but the relation Garaz has Auto (cars) is mixed !!!! For Garaz with id 2 i have random auto (cars) pls help

Comment: I have added an example query, and if that doesn't help you really should post another question

Comment: Hi thnx for helping me, and OK I get it, but I don't understand how to read from ResaultSet rs in the way that: ArrayList <Garaz> contains objects (Garaz) and each Garaz object contains ArrayList <Auto>. So I have big problem with ctreating 2 ArrayLists by reading data from rs (ResaultSet) - I have all Garaz and all Auto from DB tables, but the relation is mixed.... Like Garaz1 cointains random Auto (cars)

Comment: As I said: post another question with all the details. Comments are not really suitable for this.

Comment: That question does not contain any details, nor an actual question. I'd suggest you update it so people will actually be able to give you a suitable answer.

Comment: I have updated it, my question is simple - I have rs with ResaultSet NOW how to create 2 ArrayLists (one is part of another) to keep the relation Auto is part of Garaz based on G_ID